# sequential learning reference request

Tags: st.statistics, machine-learning

I would like to find a book for master math student about the following topics.

I don't know the field and I don't want to be lost in details so if it could be an straight forward please.

I'm a math studen but I would like to apply myselft to artificial intelligence so, I would like the books  is applied and contains images. Illustrations (graph of function, schema) are important for me as exemples and remarks.

> 1) Sequential learning problems, Stochastic Gradient Optimisation.
>
> 2) Learning with expert advices, mirror
>   descent.
>
> 3) Learning in an unknown environnement. Exploration/exploitation
>   trade-off,  Information-Theoretic lower bounds.

Thank you for your help.